# Multiple answers from that look like Spam

Tags: discussion, support, answers, spam, users

I'm particularly concerned with the contributions from [this user](https://pm.stackexchange.com/users/42651/overwatch-media), namely

- https://pm.stackexchange.com/a/30244/27189
- https://pm.stackexchange.com/a/30246/27189

having in all of the answers

> Disclaimer: We are a Microsoft Partner. We help businesses start and
> maintain their company as business consultants providing business and
> website services; and this is only our advice.

While it's great they answer questions, this constant "Disclaimer" is in the Spam borderline because that information is irrelevant.

How to proceed?

Comment: Is their content relevant? Do their answers indeed answer the question?

Comment: Note that *not* having the disclaimer would be an offence and possibly flag worthy, see [What are the “spam” and “rude or abusive” (offensive) flags, and how do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/58035/269301)

Comment: The answers are all generally low quality, but they don’t seem to cross the line into obvious spam. It’s an ambiguous data set, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion, the

> Disclaimer: We are a Microsoft Partner.

part is necessary in order to *avoid* being flagged for spam.

The rest of it, though, is irrelevant. My suggestion would therefore be to pare down the disclaimer.